# Application with separate toolbar and borders for each window

Tags: winapi, win32gui

Problem:

Maybe this is more "philosophical" question, then winapi, but
is it possible to have a windows application where for example ***Main window has green title bar and borders*** and after clicking on some button we get a ***child window which will have blue title bar and borders***. I saw some win32 api examples but I'm not sure if it is possible to have an application, where hypothetically ***each window has own title bar color, border or theme and if it could be done programmatically through winapi.***

Something like this:

Parent Window

[image: Parent Window]

Child Window:

[image: Child Window]

Any answer will help. Thank you.

Comment: See [Nonclient Area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162743.aspx). Also, what you declared to be a *"child window"* is probably an owned window, or just another top-level window. It's certainly not a child window, though.

Comment: Thank you. Ok so for each another top-level window it's possible to define it's own title bar etc. through obtaining a GetWindowDC or GetDCEx function.

Comment: You define the visual appearance of the nonclient area by handling the [WM_NCPAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212.aspx) message. Passing it's *wParam* to [GetDCEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144873.aspx) gets you a DC for painting. Rendering is done using [DrawFrameControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480.aspx) (or [DrawThemeBackground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773289.aspx) if you want to get all frisky and use [Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373487.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you. Now I have a clue. Also this is helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559385/Custom-Controls-in-Win32-API-The-Basics